# Sum causes a recursion problem

Tags: bugs, summation, recursion

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and Fixed 13.3.1**

---

```
Sum[((-1)^(i + 1)*Binomial[n, i]*(n - i)!)/n!, {i, 1, n}]
```

This cause a Recursion problem.

---

As the comment said, If simplify the formula and then sum it, problem vanished.

```
((-1)^(i + 1)*Binomial[n, i]*(n - i)!)/n! // FullSimplify // Sum[#, {i, 1, n}] &
```

Comment: I am unsure of why that happens but is equivalent to ```Sum[(-1)^(i + 1)1/i!,{i,1,n}]``` which does evaluate. In fact the summand doesn't even depend on ```n```.

Comment: +1 Add a `FullSimplify` at the end and you will get a much simpler result.

Comment: This bug seems to have been present since at least version 10.

Comment: The problem exists even in version 8.0.4: the computation continues an hour or more (until I stop it) without any result or warning. But in version 5.2.0 the correct result appears immediately.

Comment: The output may give a hint, especially the end of it `Hold[Hold[
   RuleCondition[$ConditionHold[$ConditionHold[
      System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[Sum`SumIntegerFunction], 
       Hold[Sum`SumIntegerFunction, 
        Sum`SumIntegerFunctionAsymptoticTerm, 
        Sum`IntegerFunctionAsymptoticProductDecompose], 
       "Sum`SumIntegerFunction`"]]], System`Dump`TestLoad]]][(1/
 n!)(-1)^(1 + Sum`FiniteSumDump`l)
   Binomial[n, 
   Sum`FiniteSumDump`l] (-Sum`FiniteSumDump`l + 
     n)!, {Sum`FiniteSumDump`l, 197, n}]`

Comment: Also `Integrate` appears in the error message.

Comment: I see in the doc that Sum was updated in v7.

Comment: No problem running the command in V 13.3.1. No recursion error